# Using the MYOB ODBC driver, can I update invoices?

Tags: myob

I'm using the MYOB ODBC driver to export some job and charging details from a custom application. Is there any way to update an existing invoice using ODBC, or can I only insert new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I donot think you can by using the import_xxxx tables via the MYOB ODBC Driver, you can only import by using the MYOB Import wizard.

Comment: Yep, this is the case, unfortunately :(

Comment: Hi Brent,I asked MYOB, they replied me that it is possible by adding IDENTIFY_BY parameter in the connection string, such as IDENTIFY_BY = CARD_NAME or IDENTIFY_BY = CARD_ID or IDENTIFY_BY = RECORD_ID. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`MYOB` does not allow updating sales invoices or purchase invoices. You can only insert them by `MYOB ODBC`. Moreover,  it only allows updating Cards (Customers, Suppliers, Employees and Jobs ).